# How to remove bullet from cvlistdoubleitem?

Tags: lists, moderncv

I was trying to make a 2 column list using `cvlistdoubleitem` but I could not remove the bullets.

```
\section{References}
\cvlistdoubleitem{a}{b}
\cvlistdoubleitem{c}{d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\cvlistdoubleitem`. Use `cvcolumns` instead.
From `moderncv` examples:

```
\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default `\cvlistdoubleitem` is set with a symbol as defined in `\listitemsymbol`. You can remove this via a redefinition of `\listitemsymbol`:

```
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{}
```

Note that this would affect the use of `\cvlistitem` as well, so you may want to limit the scope of this redefinition.